# Me sale un error (';' expected)en mi estructura do while

Tags: condiciones, while

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que error estoy cometiendo ahora, no entiendo como funciona esto, que es lo que esta mal ,a mi me parece que todo esta bien peor salen estos errores, por favor alguien me ayude, o me corrija por que estoy perdido con esto

aqui les dejo le codigo en java para que me puedan ayudar

```js
public static void main(String[]args){
        int canalbaniles=0,edad,cancarpint=0,contador,mayoredad=-99999,sumaedades;
        double pedacarpin;
        char profesion;
        contador=1;
        sumaedades=0;
        do
        edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la edad"));
        while (edad > 0){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"__Menu de empleado "+contador+"__");
        profesion=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la profesion C:carpintero , A:albañil").charAt(0);
        
        if(profesion=="C"){
        cancarpint=cancarpint+1;
        sumaedades=sumaedades+edad;
        pedacarpin=cancarpint/sumaedades;
        
        }
        if(profesion=="A"){
        canalbaniles=canalbaniles+1;
        }
        contador=contador+1;
    }
        if (edad>mayoredad){
            mayoredad=edad;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1. Pon la etiqueta correspondiente en la pregunta (java), 2. esa no es la sintaxis de `do while`...

Comment: La estructura do-while requiere llaves entre medias, y acabar con un punto y coma. Es decir `do {... }while();`. Luego los errores de if es porque compruebas una cadena, porque lo tienes con comillas dobles. Cambia los valores y ponlos entre comillas simples

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código hay varios errores no solamente lo que pones en el título, he cambiado varias lineas del código que compartes; espero que puedas comparar y verificar en que estás fallando.
Entre los errores que te puedo mencionar son:
1)Tener en cuenta que al usar do while tiene que haber una condición para que salga el bucle, por ello pido ingresar la edad antes de ingresar al do while y nuevamente pido la edad antes de cerrar el while.
2) Comenzando el bucle do while lo quieres mostrar es un mensaje, entonces usa showMessageDialog en lugar de showInputDialog.
3) Seguramente tu programa no va dar el resultado que esperas porque tu variable sumaedades no está bien definido, esto no lo corrigí porque no se cual es el resultado que buscas en tu programa.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        int canalbaniles=0,edad,cancarpint=0,contador,mayoredad=-99999,sumaedades;
        double pedacarpin;
        String profesion;
        contador=1;
        sumaedades=0;
        edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la edad"));
        do{            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"__Menu de empleado "+contador+"__");//Usa el show message
            profesion=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la profesion C:carpintero , A:albañil");

            if(profesion.equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
            cancarpint=cancarpint+1;
            sumaedades=sumaedades+edad;
            pedacarpin=cancarpint/sumaedades;

            }
            if(profesion.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            canalbaniles=canalbaniles+1;
            }
            
            contador=contador+1;
            
            if (edad>mayoredad){
            mayoredad=edad;
            }
            edad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese la edad"));
        }while (edad > 0);        
    }
```

Comment: podrías especificarle qué está mal? para que no sea un "hacerle la tarea"

Comment: SI YA LO HICE ,xd estaba alrevez